# Minified React error #152 - how to resolve this?

Tags: reactjs

I am getting below error even though I am building using dev environment. Below is my package.json file.

> Error: "for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings."

*Package.json* file:

```
 "scripts": {
    "compile": "webpack",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

I do npm run build and then npm run start. Still I am getting the same minified error, I tried to delete bundle.js or ./dist folder and done building in dev environment, still I face the same issue.

Could anyone help me, how can I avoid this minified version and debug the files easily in local?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The error description is [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=152&args[]=ni), you return nothing as result of `render`method of you react component. Return something else instead of it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have checked this error, Somehow I have resolved my this error by uncommenting my recent code and figured out a syntax issue. But how can i avoid this minified code while working in dev environment? I can't actually debug code line by line in chrome developer tools when it is minified.

Comment: @IAmRkrishnaV21 If you want to have readable minified source code, you need to use "source map", isiest way in webpack is using `devtool: 'inline-source-map'` (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/), but it is another theme not correlating with your original question. If you resolved the original question with my answer, check it as right answer, please.

Comment: Thanks for providing easiest way in webpack. My actual question was the same thing => how can i avoid this minified version and debug the files easily in local. I was prompted the same link you provided given by react but anyway that's a syntax error. The later solution worked for me avoiding minified version to debug easily so i am marking it as right answer as I cant do this for your previous comment.

Answer (score 34):

Remove any comment inside `render`/ `return` method

> I used this regex in VSCode to find the troublesome comments:
> (\s*\n?\s*//

[image]

More help [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8687)

Comment: FYI: Just two slashes (without anything after) is enough to screw things up and get this 152 error. Took awhile to find this. Super annoying!

Answer (score 6):

In case it helps someone, I resolved this problem by returning null instead of false (my function is wrapped inside an HOC)

Edit: sometimes I did not want to render anything. In such case, I returned false in the render method as something like this:

```js
    render(){
        return condition && <ThingsIWantToDisplay/>; //condition is a boolean
    }
```

The component class is then wrapped within an HOC (to provide React Context) like this:

```js
export default HOC(Component);
```

When `condition` is `false`, an error occurs in the production build.

Changing the render function as shown below alleviated the problem:

```js
    render(){
        return condition?<ThingsIWantToDisplay/>:null; //condition is a boolean
    }
```

Comment: You saved my life with this answer for a totally different problem ! Thank you so much !

Comment: What is an HOC? High-Order Component? Hall Of Challenges? Happy On Crack? Man I hate acronyms in tech discussions and documentation.

Comment: Like many React related stuffs, *context* is the key.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue
check your useState import

`import { useState } from 'react/cjs/react.production.min';`
change into
`import react,{usestate} from 'react'`

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. So i removed comments inside my render function and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally imported it from here:

`import {useState} from "react/cjs/react.production.min";`

use import from `import React, {useState} from 'react';` instead

That fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

In our instance, this was not related to comments inside the react HTML at all, it had to do with CMS changes. If you go through your react HTML and find no comments, try taking a look at other tools you are using that may be having an effect on your site.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32782361)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
`//`
Remove All Comments in This Component

otherwise

apply condition `&&` don't do like this:

`{condition && (<Permission allowed={[]} />)}`

Do like this:

`{condition ? (<Permission allowed={[]} />) : null}`

Comment: how does this solve it?