# Minified React Error when app is in production mode (built)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, redux-saga, saga

[image]

Do not know why or what is causing this errors when the app is built. There is no error on development. This occurs when redirecting user to a success page on successful signup (works perfect in dev). And the error is not from the page it is redirecting to, as I change the redirect path to another page and the errors still show up.

**Webpack Config**

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin');
// const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
const publicPath = '/';

// Make sure any symlinks in the project folder are resolved:
const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);

// plugins
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

// the path(s) that should be cleaned
const pathsToClean = ['dist', 'build'];

// the clean options to use
const cleanOptions = {
  root: __dirname,
  verbose: false, // Write logs to console.
  dry: false
};

// Get the root path (assuming your webpack config is in the root of your project!)
const currentPath = path.join(__dirname);

// Create the fallback path (the production .env)
const basePath = currentPath + '/.env';

// We're concatenating the environment name to our filename to specify the correct env file!
const envPath = basePath + '.' + process.env.NODE_ENV;

// Check if the file exists, otherwise fall back to the production .env
const finalPath = fs.existsSync(envPath) ? envPath : basePath;

// Set the path parameter in the dotenv config
const env = dotenv.config({ path: finalPath }).parsed;

// reduce it to a nice object, the same as before
const envKeys = Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, next) => {
  prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
  return prev;
}, {});

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', 'react-hot-loader/patch', './src/index.js'],
  output: {
    // The build folder.
    path: resolveApp('dist'),
    // Generated JS file names (with nested folders).
    // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
    // We don't currently advertise code splitting but Webpack supports it.
    filename: 'assets/js/[name].[hash:8].js',
    chunkFilename: 'assets/js/[name].[hash:8].chunk.js',
    // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
    publicPath,
    hotUpdateChunkFilename: 'hot/hot-update.js',
    hotUpdateMainFilename: 'hot/hot-update.json'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './src/index.js',
    compress: true,
    port: 3005, // port number
    historyApiFallback: true,
    quiet: true
    // disableHostCheck: true //unsafe for production. Change it later.
  },
  // resolve alias (Absolute paths)
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      Components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
      Containers: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/containers/'),
      Assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/'),
      Util: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/util/'),
      Routes: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/routes/'),
      Constants: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/constants/'),
      Redux: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/redux/'),
      Data: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/data/')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: { minimize: true }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
      },
      // Scss compiler
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        // uglifyOptions: {
        //   compress: false,
        //   ecma: 6,
        //   mangle: true
        // },
        uglifyOptions: {
          parse: {
            ecma: 8
          },
          compress: {
            ecma: 5,
            warnings: false,
            comparisons: false
          },
          mangle: {
            safari10: true
          },
          output: {
            ecma: 5,
            comments: false,
            ascii_only: true
          }
        },
        sourceMap: true
      }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
  },
  performance: {
    hints: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warning' : false
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'src/assets/img', to: 'assets/img' },
      { from: 'src/assets/fonts', to: 'assets/fonts' },
      { from: 'src/assets/css', to: 'assets/css' }
    ]),
    new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin(),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(pathsToClean, cleanOptions),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      filename: './index.html',
      favicon: './public/favicon.ico'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'assets/css/[name].[hash:8].css'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys)
  ]
};
```

Comment: I think it is hard to figure out what is going on. Are you able to test a minified build in your dev environment or test a non minified build in a test/prod environment where the issue appears ?

In other words, does the issue come from the minification or the environment itself ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50497026/minified-react-error-152-how-to-resolve-this

Comment: @klugjo its quite hard to track this error when the code is in built. but i can say it not the environment that is causing it, but can say for the minification as it works perfect when in development(not minified).

Comment: @KenoClayton that link did give me a solution as `devtool: 'inline-source-map'` gave me a bunch of long linki dnt know what it mean nor how `devtool: 'inline-source-map'` works